# Source of the cliche "[these] diminished times"?

Tags: expressions, quotes, cliche

I believe the phrase "diminished times" is a common expression or cliche, maybe a quotation, but I haven't been able to find the source. Is it a cliche, and where does it come from?

**P.S.** After @aparente001 posted his or her answer, I found this example from a [5/11/2000 post by Andrew McLaren](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/%22diminished$20times%22/uk.culture.language.english/fhC3F2nWmf4/cNNvEthRfBwJ) to the newsgroup uk.culture.language.english:

> Even in these diminished times, Brazil produces something like 2/3s of the world's coffee, [down] from 80% a few decades ago.

Comment: Worth pointing out that I've never encountered this phrase (AmE speaker).

Comment: @DanBron - Same here!

Answer (score 1):

I did a google search over various time periods, and the first use of the phrase “these diminished times” that I could find is http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=94932049 from 2008.

However, just "diminished times" appeared earlier.

2002: http://www2.latech.edu/~bmagee/212/pound/pact_notes.htm

2004: http://homepage.tinet.ie/~odyssey/Politics/Quotes/Steyn_Terror.html

Sorry I don't have a better answer.

Comment: +1 and thanks. On second thought "these" isn't important so I'll edit my question accordingly. I would have expected something earlier than 2002. Is it only in the last dozen years that the times have diminished so much?

Comment: @bof - You can have some fun putting custom time ranges into your google search.

Comment: I found an example from 2000. I'll edit it into my question.